# Selecting ActionBar Icon crashes application

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have been Following the post [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html) to learn more about the ActionBar in Android.

In my application i am trying to navigate to the HomeActivity from the action bar icon on every page.....This is how i handle it now but it wont work and crashes the application.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

LogCat Here:

```
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testingapp/com.testingapp.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at com.testingapp.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:49)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
03-25 20:02:26.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11346):    ... 11 more
```

menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: plz also add log with question to get more help

Comment: updated the question with logCat

Comment: where is line number 49 in HomeActivity ?

Answer (score 0):

Check line number 49, watever objects you are using in that line, please print using Log.i before line number 49. the culprit is the one that is null.

Comment: You get NULL when you come back, then it means you are using something that is destroyed, things would be clear if you can post some code very hard to figure out like this

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use `R.id.home` instead of `android.R.id.home` to get menu id if you have add menu id for menu item as :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/home" //<<< here
     ..../>
```

or to use default id you must declare menu id as `android:id="@+id/android:home"`

Comment: im trying to access the click event for the ic_launcher image when clicked to navigate back to my HomeActivity.class.....how do i do that?

Comment: @KeeanoMartin : what problem u are getting now.because you are using wrong id for accessing  home menu . if u are still getting issue then share ur menu xml file also with  question

Comment: @KeeanoMartin : why u have add Style.xml ? problem is inside Menu xml so plz add menu xml instead of Style

Comment: Sorry, updated to menu.xml for my activity. I did not alter or edit this what so ever.....I made a theme in my style.xml.

Comment: @KeeanoMartin : u have only one item i menu with id `menu_settings` then use `R.id.menu_settings` in switch case instead of `R.id.home` for starting next Activity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26899/discussion-between-keeano-martin-and--k)